# Reputation for editing tags

Tags: support, privileges

Today I edited the tag on [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/47572/possibility-of-getting-odd-pair-socks) from real-analysis to probability. At present I have low to mid 400 reputation points. According to the privileges sheet I should not be able to do that until I have 500 points. I used an edit link at the bottom of the question. Perhaps this is a bug; perhaps a feature.

Comment: Theo's answer really covers your question, but you can also get to [this specific page](http://math.stackexchange.com/suggested-edits/1552) showing the details of your edit as a suggestion that was then approved by another used by clicking the "suggested" link by your name in the [revision history](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/47572/revisions) of the question.

Comment: @Isaac: Thanks! I was looking for such a link but couldn't find it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is not a bug. As soon as you'll reach 500 reputation points, you will be able to edit tags *autonomously*, that is: without approval from a user with higher reputation. Full editing privileges will be granted from 2000 reputation points on.

In this specific instance, you suggested an edit to change the tag from [real-analysis](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/real-analysis) to [probability](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/probability) which was then approved by another user.

There's nothing wrong with that, as far as I can tell.